# Unix writing permissions for two users?

Tags: unix, permissions

I have a development machine where I have subvserions projects checked out, so my user account has ownership permissions for those files. However, they are websites, and sometimes the apache user (www-data) needs to write to the directory (temporary files, uploads, etc.).

I'm not so familiar with Unix permissions, but when I give ownership to one, the other can't write. How can I get it so that both can write to the directories? (I've changed permissions to 755 for all the dirs.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add them both to a group, and give that group writing permissions for the directory you want them both to write to.

```
Create a new group:
    $ sudo groupadd groupname

Add users to the group:
    $ sudo usermod -a -G groupname username1
    $ sudo usermod -a -G groupname username2

Set the permissions as you want them to be for everyone else. 
(755 as it is now is probably unwise...)

Set the directory ownership to the group:
    $ sudo chgrp -R groupname /directory

Give the group write permission:
    $ sudo chmod -R g+w /directory
```

If you want more users to have write access, just add them to that group using:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G groupname username
```

Comment: @user13743 Try it now, forgot the -a flag! Updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome! But `group_name username` seems to be backwards on my system; I had to user 'sudo adduser -a www-data web-directory-writers'

Comment: @user13743 No! Then you added a user web-directory-writers to the group www-data! use like this: `sudo useradd -a -G groupname username1` Don't forget the -G flag! What error do you get if you do it like that?

Comment: `>sudo adduser -a web-directory-writers www-data adduser: The user 'web-directory-writers' does not exist. ` >sudo adduser -a www-data web-directory-writers The user 'www-data' is already a member of 'web-directory-writers'.`

Comment: @user13743 You're forgetting the -G flag! `sudo adduser -a **-G** web-directory-writers www-data`

Comment: I see what's going on : `sudo useradd -a -G web-directory-writers www-data
useradd: invalid option -- a
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN`

Comment: In your answer, you recommend useradd, but those switched don't work on my system. I'm using adduser, and the results seem to be okay:
`grep writers /etc/group web-directory-writers:x:1001:www-data,target_username`

Comment: @user13743 I'm being such an ass! I keep telling you to use useradd! Use usermod! I'm so so so sorry, see my updated answer

Comment: :) I've had some of those days

Comment: @user13743 Glad it works now! :D Sorry again for the wasted time!

Comment: You saved me a bunch of time :D

Comment: @user13743 Haha! I'm very glad! ;D